# How to correctly export a module to be compiled with Babel and Webpack 5

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I was using Webpack 4 and since I updated to Webpack 5, loads of problems appeared. It's normal that things get updated and old stuff has to be removed, but in this case I am a bit lost.

I get the following error on console after compiling with Babel 7 adn Webpack 5.

> Uncaught Error: ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax, instead.

The file causing the issue exports the module as:

```
module.exports = {
```

Should I change that to something else?

I don't really understand what is going on.